# List maven dependencies without downloading jars

Tags: dependencies, maven-3

Is there a way to list dependencies for maven project without downloading jars?
I know there is maven dependency plugin available.

```
mvn dependency:tree
```

or

```
mvn dependency:list
```

However, both will attempt to download jars. Can the download phase of jars be skipped?
Is there another way? E.g. using a different tool.

Answer (score 1):

Found out that there is goal

```
mvn dependency:collect
```

However, that would download poms for dependencies only, it doesn't work for artifacts.

Answer (score 0):

I was faced by the same problem today and was not able to find any solution on the Web. Especially here ;)

Please find below a dirty-hacky-tricky solution that should work if you don't want to list transitive dependencies. (BTW I believe it's not possible to list transitive dependencies without downloading of POMs):

```
export GROUPID=org.springframework
export ARTIFACTID=spring-context
export VERSION=5.3.16
```

first of all we get POM for needed GAV:

```
mvn dependency:get -Dtransitive=false -DgroupId=${GROUPID} -DartifactId=${ARTIFACTID} -Dversion=${VERSION} -Dpackaging=pom
```

And here we **TRY** to resolve its dependencies in **offline** and **debug** modes:

```
mvn -f -o -X ~/.m2/repository/`echo "${GROUPID}/${ARTIFACTID}" | sed 's/\./\//'`/${VERSION}/*.pom dependency:list -DexcludeTransitive
```

mvn will fail with some intresting lines in output:

```
[DEBUG] Dependency collection stats {ConflictMarker.analyzeTime=365032, ConflictMarker.markTime=106055, ConflictMarker.nodeCount=5, ConflictIdSorter.graphTime=201747, ConflictIdSorter.topsortTime=214050, ConflictIdSorter.conflictIdCount=4, ConflictIdSorter.conflictIdCycleCount=0, ConflictResolver.totalTime=1708152, ConflictResolver.conflictItemCount=4, DefaultDependencyCollector.collectTime=4415754, DefaultDependencyCollector.transformTime=3650266}
[DEBUG] org.springframework:spring-context:jar:5.3.16
[DEBUG]    org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:5.3.16:compile
[DEBUG]    org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.3.16:compile
[DEBUG]    org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.3.16:compile
[DEBUG]    org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:5.3.16:compile
```

As we can see it's a list of dependencies. It comes right before mvn fails.

PS: I don't recommend it for production environments. Only suitable for one-time jobs.