# Dealing with quarantined jars in maven

Tags: java, maven, aether

I have an internal jfrog artifactory which contains artifacts from various maven repos. There are some jars that are quarantined as they have high CVE vulnerabilities. I want to get the dependency tree (either through mvn or through java code) without downloading the jars as they are quarantined(405 status code), but the pom are not quarantined. Is there any way this can be achieved ?

Comment: So `mvn dependency:tree` fails because of the missing JARs?

Comment: Yes .. When maven tries to generate the dependency tree, it starts downloading pom and then jar, and the jar download fails. So `mvn dependency:tree` fails

Comment: Does this answer your question? [List maven dependencies without downloading jars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66490343/list-maven-dependencies-without-downloading-jars)